# passing array on the heap and on the stack to function

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, new-operator

I have a simple c++ question concerning passing an array to a function foo(). Assume I have two arrays A and B:

```
double* A=new double[3];
```

and

```
double B[3];
```

When I pass both to the function

```
foo(double* A; double *B)
```

which is intended to manipulates both arrays. However by executing

```
foo(A,B)
```

foo is acting on a copy of A and only the changes to B remain when leaving foo(). 
This is not the case if foo is defined as

```
foo(double* &A; double *B).
```

My question: Why is a copy of a created although I pass the address of A like double* A (as in the case of B) in the first example of foo()?

Comment: The first line of code does not compile. Also, what you are passing to the function are in both cases pointers. And in both cases the function can modify the arrays through these pointers. Please improve your question.

Comment: In the first declaration of foo, both pointers are passed by value, so inside foo you will have copies of A and B. In the second declaration, A is passed by reference, which under the hood is a pointer to a pointer, which allows you to alter A inside foo. Are you aware of this, or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: show your code of foo() method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> foo is acting on a copy of A and only the changes to B remain when leaving foo().

What exactly are you doing inside of foo? Changes to the objects themself should be visible outside of foo in both cases. If you are trying to change the value of pointer A, it won't be visible outside of foo - a copy of the pointer is passed to the function, but of course it still points to the same array.

Comment: I found my mistake. Inside foo() I was swapping pointers. In the first case I swapped only the copy and was wondering about my result when I manipulated the arrays later outside foo. Nevertheless: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass an array reference to a function you have to use a double pointer reference:

```
foo(double** A, double **B);

double** A=new complex<double>[3];
```